# Can we pass 200 or 201 response from one controller method?

Tags: rest, put

I have REST api with PUT method for updating resource ,I want to send 200 if resource is updated and 201 if resource is created from controller. Is it possible to return one of response code from one controller mapping depending upon resource is created or updated ?

I checked on internet but not able to find absolute answer

Comment: What servers / languages / frameworks are you using?

Comment: In case you create a new resource as part of a POST or PUT request you have to return a `201 Created` response with a `Location` header that contains the URI of the created resource. For updates you can return any applicable status code, i.e. 200 or 204.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.